# How to configure login on protractor test if we are already login

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

i like to modify [loginConf](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js) to match my backend which is php. So it will try to login if no session found in `webDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

here my modification on `onPrepare function`

```
onPrepare: function () {
var sessId;
//redirected url if you already login
var requiredLoginUrl = 'http://localhost/somesite/home';
browser.driver.get('http://localhost/somesite/login')
  .then(function () {
    // other option
    browser.driver.getSession()
      .then(function(session) {
        sessId = session.id_;
        console.log('Session id  : ', sessId);
      });

    browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()
      .then(function (url) {
        console.log('current url is : ', url);
        if (url.includes(requiredLoginUrl)) {
          console.log('already login');
          return;
        } else {
          console.log('need login');
          browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userNameField')).sendKeys('user');
          browser.driver.findElement(by.id('passwordField')).sendKeys('pass');
          browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.btn-primary')).click();
          return;
        }
      });
  });
```

}

### resource

1. [Selenium tutorial](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)
2. [Protractor api](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api)